# How to remove element from list if part of it appears in another list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

So let's say I have

```
list_1 = ["ABC_123,Hello,World", "DEF_456,Hello,World"]
list_2 = ["ABC_123,Something,Else", "KOR_729,Something,Else"]
```

What I want to do is remove the elements from `list_1` that contain the same first part of the string as in `list_2`, in this case `"ABC_123"`.

The expected output would be

```
list_3 = ["DEF_456,Hello,World"]
```

which is list 1, but with `"ABC_123,Hello,World"` removed since the part `"ABC_123"` appears in an element of list 2.

Comment: "The first part of the string as in list 2"... what do you mean by "First part of the string". Are you saying that you are wanting to look for `list2[0].split(',')[0]` inside of `[x.split(',') for x in list1]`? Like you are wanting to search all comma delimited strings inside of list1 to see if they are equal to `ABC_123` (but you don't care about `something` or `else`?)

Comment: Turn `list_2` into a set of prefixes. Then loop through `list_1`, testing if the prefix of each string is in the set of prefixes.

Comment: @JNevill Yes, by the first part of the string I mean `list_2.split(sep=",")[0]` but for every single element in `list_2`, (not just for `ABC_123`) and check if they are in an element of `list_1`.

Comment: Please show what you've tried.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Barmar Hey, yeah after some trying I was able to get it to work and I posted a solution, it seems to work, but if anyone has a better solution please feel free to post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright so after some trying I was able to get it to work.

Here is a solution:

```
list_1 = ["ABC_123,Hello,World","DEF_456,Hello,World"]
list_2 = ["ABC_123,Something,Else","KOR_729,Something,Else"]

list_2_prefix = set([x.split(sep=",")[0] for x in list_2])
list_3 = [x for x in list_1 if x.split(sep=",")[0] not in list_2_prefix]
```

The output is:

```
list_3 = ["DEF_456,Hello,World"]
```

Comment: I would put the `set()` call where you assign to `list_2_prefix`, so it doesn't do it every time through the list comprehension.